# application custom stock icons not working in ubuntu unity top panel menu (aka appmenu) ("Menus Have Icons" ON)

Tags: icons, appmenu

I recently noticed that in ubuntu unity the top menu of my apps does not show the (custom) icons I added to the gtk stock, but only the basic gtk stock icons.

This happens only since the top menu is displayed in the unity top panel (appmenu) and not in the application window.
In place of the correct custom icons I see "gtk-missing-image".
On my apps toolbars and other menus those icons are displayed properly, the problem is only with the top menu.

This happens either with pygtk2 (e.g. http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/) and gobject introspection (e.g. http://www.giuspen.com/nautilus-pyextensions/).
I use gtk ui manager after integrating the stock icons this way:

```
factory = gtk.IconFactory()
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(filepath)
iconset = gtk.IconSet(pixbuf)
factory.add(stock_name, iconset)
factory.add_default()
```

If anybody solved this problem please help.
Cheers,
Giuseppe.

Comment: I noticed that inkscape has the same problem

Comment: I edited from unity-2d to unity since I noticed the problem exists also there, do I have to create a new question or this is enough?

Answer (score 4):

The AppIndicator framework needs to know about the icons.  To do this they need to be in a theme directory, or part of the custom theme for the application.  You can add a theme directory using `app_indicator_set_icon_theme_path()`.  This allows the application indicator service to know where to look for your custom icons.  You can also install the icons in the default icon theme which is located in `/usr/share/themes/hicolor`.

Lastly, as a total hack, you can generate them on the fly.  This is what is done by `indicator-multiload`.  It is not recommended, so I won't link to it, but if it is something you need look there.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been wondering about this, since it seems to me to "sometimes" honor icons loaded explicitly from other absolute locations with no rhyme or reason to when it no longer remembers the icon.

Comment: OK I can use set_icon_theme_path() for appindicator but what about the appmenu (the top menu that is embedded in the top panel when the app is maximized)

Comment: For that you need to add a theme directory in GTK+.  That's done with gtk_icon_theme_append_search_path().

Comment: I made gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path() but it doesn't work. The icons are visible only after I enable the appindicator and so set the appindicator.set_icon_theme_path()

Comment: After I set appindicator status to set_status(appindicator.STATUS_PASSIVE) the icons are not visible anymore in unity top panel appmenu. The only solution is to completely disable appmenu using os.environ['UBUNTU_MENUPROXY'] = '0' and keep the menu inside my application.